RPM: Best Practice for %post Removing Installed File
My package includes an executable that needs functions from libcrypto.so.1.1. Since that library is not installed by default on RedHat 9 (and Rocky, AlmaLinux, CentOS Stream, etc.), I include it in my package.
The issue is that if the system is FIPS enabled, the functions in my copy of libcrypto will fail, because FIPS doesn't allow crypto functions that are not part of a system library.
My potential solution is as follows:

Add Recommends: ( openssl-libs-1.1.1k or compat-openssl11 ) to the package file
In the %post section, add if [ -e /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 ]; then rm -f $MYLIBS/libcrypto.so.1.1; fi

This would have the following effects:
On RedHat 8 systems, libcrypto.so.1.1 is already provided by openssl-libs-1.1.1k (because of many dependencies), no the line in the %post will remove my packaged library. This will allow the software to work in FIPS mode.
On RedHat 9 systems, libcrypto.so.3 is used instead, so if the system has Internet access to the RedHat repositories, then the compat-openssl11 package will be installed, providing libcrypto.so.1.1, so the %post script will work as above, allowing the software to work in FIPS mode.
On RedHat 9 isolated (air gapped) systems, the compat-openssl11 package will not be available, but the libcrypto.so.1.1 library included in my package will still be available, allowing the software to work, at least on systems that are not in FIPS mode. (But then, if the system is air gapped, FIPS mode is not really needed anyway.)

I haven't tested this yet, and I'm wondering if running `rm -f` in a %post script is an appropriate solution to the problem.
